# capture sprite with all its children - cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

![reference images]https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N1ot.jpg

In screen1 user tap on a nail and screen2 shows up where user make designs on nail (basically add some layers on nail) after that it looks like screen3.

now What I want is when user come back to screen 1 it should see the nail he designed at the place of nail he tapped.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

ps:

I tried nail_sprite->getTexture() but it return just nail sprite not its child.

Child of nail_sprite include layers where user draw some thing at run time so I can't just pick up the whole draw_layer I have to only capture the part user draw something.

Answer (score 1):

**First method** is to pass the selected sprite-nail to the next scene by argument. So try this in Scene1:

```
var nailSprite1;
var nailSprite2;
var nailSprite3;
//and so...

var selectedNailSprite = nailSprite1;
```

Scene3:

```
selectedNailSprite.addChild(otherSprite);
```

Scene1:

```
selectedNailSprite.getChildren();
```

and after returning to the Scene1 you will have sprite with its all children. Don't recreate it, share it between scenes :)

**Second method** to achieve that is to make screenshot of Sprite from Scene 3 and save it on the device. Next you can load it in Scene 1.

**Third method** is to save nail's structure from Scene3 to XML or other format and load it in Scene1 :D

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved my day.
I am gonna post answer in my scenario too.

Answer (score 0):

here is my implementation in light of @sortris first method.

I created a method addLayer in parentLayer when ever I add a layer in child I call parent method too.
and in case of stencil.drawDot when I draw a node in child layer I draw a node in parent Sprite too by calling parent method to drawDot.